# In Xalan XSLT 1.0, need a function to return all child element names

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xalan

Assume I have this XML...

```
<books>
  <book>
    <author>
    <title>
    <publish_date>
    <isbn_number>
  <book>
</books>
```

...how can I write a function, or use built in functions, to return a string that is just a comma-separated concat of all child element names of book? like this...

```
author,title,publish_date,isbn_number
```

I need this to print the first line header in a csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following minimal stylesheet works on your given input (modified to be well-formed):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="book/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @RaffiM - This is possible with a `for-each`, but it's definitely not necessary.

Comment: @RaffiM - Try changing the template match to `match="/books/book/*"`